# How to restore the panel with viewport navigation tools

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I remember there being a panel with buttons to zoom in or out or pan in the viewport but it seems to have gone somehow. How can I add it back?

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/ed9c8983c21ddea1bcb53b9cebc66433.png]

Comment: I fail to remember any panel like that even though I use Blender daily for the last 3 years. You must be mistaken. You can check previous versions here: http://download.blender.org/release/ and see it is not there for yourself. See info on navigation in the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html

Comment: I figured it out it was an addon I just found it.

Answer (score 1):

The tabs on the toolbar come from addons, if one is missing then the addon that put it there has been disabled or uninstalled.

The steps you list are [available using the mouse and keyboard](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html), use <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> to pan, the <kbd>[image: MMB] scroll wheel</kbd> as well as <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> will zoom in/out.

Answer (score 1):

Like the others who have answered/commented, I can't remember ever seeing a panel with navigation tools in the current or past versions of Blender.

### Are / were you using the (unstable) Blender 2.8 Alpha?

One possibility I can think of is that you've been using the recent (unstable) version 2.8 Alpha, and then reverted back to the (stable) version 2.79.

This is what the "gizmo tool" looks like in Blender 2.8 Alpha:

[image]

If that's what you were using, and now for some reason you are using Blender 2.79, then you can find the releases [here](https://builder.blender.org/download/) to install Blender 2.8 back. Be aware that **2.8 Alpha is still unstable and you must be very careful about using it for important projects**.

If that's what you were using, and you are still using 2.8, then you might have hidden the Gizmo. You can bring it back by reactivating (if needed) the *Overlays* and, in the Overlays menu, activating *Gizmo*:

[image]